# How can I split at word boundaries with regexes?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I'm trying to do this:

```
import re
sentence = "How are you?"
print(re.split(r'\b', sentence))
```

The result being

```
[u'How are you?']
```

I want something like `[u'How', u'are', u'you', u'?']`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: [Python cannot split by empty string](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-August/024753.html).

Comment: Also, it should return `[u'How', u' ', u'are', u' ', u'you', u'?']`

Comment: @KennyLau Yes, correct, but that is not that important, I'm ok with either whitespace returned or ignored since filtering it is trivial.

Comment: So which one should I implement?

Comment: Another reason to learn [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, Python cannot split by empty strings.

To get around this, you would need to use `findall` instead of `split`.

Actually `\b` just means word boundary.

It is equivalent to `(?<=\w)(?=\W)|(?<=\W)(?=\w)`.

That means, the following code would work:

```
import re
sentence = "How are you?"
print(re.findall(r'\w+|\W+', sentence))
```

Comment: Well, OP needs no whitespace only tokens.

Comment: Split by `\b` will produce whitespace also, because `\b` is zero length.

Comment: All I meant is that `\w+|[^\w\s]+` might be more appropriate.

Comment: It matches `['How', ' ', 'are', ' ', 'you', '?']`

Comment: That is what `\b` is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: [Nope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237594/how-can-i-split-at-word-boundaries-with-regexes/37237815?noredirect=1#comment62007177_37237594).

Comment: `\b.*?\b` could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
split = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", "How are you?")
print(split)
```

---

**Output:**

```
['How', 'are', 'you', '?']
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/xHt2l2)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW3xS6/1)

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
"[\w']+|[.,!?;]"

    1st Alternative: [\w']+
        [\w']+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
            ' the literal character '
    2nd Alternative: [.,!?;]
        [.,!?;] match a single character present in the list below
            .,!?; a single character in the list .,!?; literally
```

Comment: Why did you include the `'` character?

Comment: If the user has another string with word`'`s containing `'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to `split` on word boundaries:

```
re.split(r"\b\W\b", "How are you?") # Reprocess list to split on special characters.
# Result: ['How', 'are', 'you?']
```

and using `findall` on word boundaries

```py
re.findall(r"\b\w+\b", "How are you?")
# Result: ['How', 'are', 'you']
```