# how to read and compare different words in a single line of a file which is saved in utf-8 format? in python?

Tags: python, file-handling, python-unicode

I want to read in word by word a specific line of a file (which is in UTF-8 encoding format). I can read the entire line with the code:

```
read_language = open(X, "r", encoding='UTF8') # here X is a predefined file name

T=read_language.readline()
```

The main problem is the utf-8 space is not same as normal space character.

this is for reading linse but I want to read each word from line and know the index number of each word. I also want to compare it with predefined word.

The string in my file is `समीकरण ज + अ`. I want to read the first word (`समीकरण`), then the next word, and so on, until the line ends. I also want to compare check for `+`s in an if statement to perform further operations.

Comment: Maybe you can split each line at its word boundaries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237594/how-can-i-split-at-word-boundaries-with-regexes

Comment: it almost worked but it is printing only some part of the words for example my string in line is  "अथवा  समीकरण aa "     but the समीकरण is printed as सम and अथवा is printed as अथव

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    read_language = open(X, "r", encoding='UTF8')#X and Y are predefined filenames 
    output_file = open(Y, "w", encoding='UTF8') 
    T=read_language.readline()
    for idx, word in enumerate(re.split(r"\s", T)):
        print (idx, word)
        if idx==2:
            print(word)
            output_file.write(word)
   read_language.close()
   output_file.close()
```

## this works for me for specific index even in utf-8(unicode) format

Answer (score 0):

This function will read a line and print all the words. It splits the line using a regex of white spaces (\s) and adds the index using the [enumerate](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) function.

```
def read_words(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r", encoding="UTF8") as read_language:
        line = read_language.readline()
        for idx, word in enumerate(re.split(r"\s", line)):
            print (idx, word)
```

you can upgrade it to be a generator using yield:

```
def read_words(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r", encoding="UTF8") as read_language:
        line = read_language.readline()
        for idx, word in enumerate(re.split(r"\s", line)):
            yield (idx, word)
```

You can add the compare function inside the for loop and perform any logic you want with the word.